# Failed to connect mailserver

Tags: php

[image: Here's the image of the error.]

Hello? I hope someone will help me with this. Here's the problem, my code for sending an e-mail to Gmail is not working. I've already installed hMailServer but I don't know how to configure it.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much.

```
<?php
  $to      = 'kurokonobasket189@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'the subject';
  $message = 'hello';
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  echo "Message sent!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used hotmail for email sending purposes, but can you have a look 
[here](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-windows-live-hotmail-smtp-settings-1170861)?
There is said that SMTP port for hotmail is **587**.

Your PHP error message is connected with probably wrong set SMTP port which is **25** by default.

You must open your php.ini file (I can see you are using WAMP server, so click on the icon in the tray > PHP > php.ini) and find proper configuration entries like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

Then just try to set `smtp_port = 587` in the config and **restart** WAMP server.